# Вывод tv параметров в modx revo

Tags: php, modx

Хочу вывести теги к каждой статье путем выбора нужных в настройках. Например, чекбоксами. В возможных параметрах пишу `html==html||css==css`. При выборе ничего не выводит. Зато если указать какое-нибудь значение по умолчанию, все отображается. То есть вызов `tv` параметра верен. Сокращенную схему в возможных значениях тоже пробовал - `html||css`. Результата ноль. Все форумы уже обошел. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1):

Если просто требуется выводить списком, те метки, которые отмечены, то достаточно в `"Параметрах вывода"` указать разделитель. Например (`,`).

В нужном месте шаблона вывести `[[*tags]]`. На выходе будет список отмеченных чекбоксов через запятую. *(хотя, я бы лучше использовал множественный выбор, принцип вывода там такой-же)*

Но, наверно такой вариант вывода не интересен. Можно написать простенький сниппет, который будет принимать тот-же список с разделителем и выводить метки уже в нужном виде (например ссылкой вида `<a href="#css">css</a> ...`).

Создаём сниппет **tags**.

В нужном месте шаблона:

```
[[!tags? &list=`[[*tv_tags]]`]]
```

Где `[[*tv_tags]]` - список меток с разделителем.

Сам сниппет примерно такой:

```
if($list == '') {return 'нет меток';} // Если нет меток

$tags = explode(",", $list); // Разбиваем с помощью нашей запятой

foreach ($tags as $val) { // перебираем и делаем ссылку
    $output .= '<a href="#'.$val.'">'.$val.'</a> ';
}

return $output;
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но по-прежнему ничего не работает. Оба способа попробовал. Причем во втором пишет "нет меток". То есть будто поле "возможные значения" вообще не учитывается. Может с чем-то конфликует? Я ставил только pdoTools, но в этом наборе нет аналогичных сниппетов.

Comment: Изменил тип tv на "текст", удалил все содержимое. Зашел в элемент, на котором тестировал, а там уже было вписано значение "HTML" (которое не так давно соответствовало первому чекбоксу).

Comment: Проблему решил. Спасибо. Дело было в не совсем некорректном вызове tv.